# How to solve Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingReferencesException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make extension for VS2013 preview, here is my try on GitHub: https://github.com/Heather/Nemerle/tree/VS2013

But for now I'm getting:

```
07.08.2013 9:25:05 - The following target products have been selected...
07.08.2013 9:25:05 -    Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview
07.08.2013 9:25:05 - 
07.08.2013 9:25:05 - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview...
07.08.2013 9:25:05 - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingReferencesException: This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:
- Visual Studio MPF
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForInstallBlockers(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, Boolean isNestedExtension, Boolean& olderVersionInstalled)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean perMachine, Boolean isNestedExtension, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, UInt64 totalBytesToWrite, UInt64& totalBytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

I used to add most of every needed extension and can't understand where does it come from?

Here is extension project file in current state: https://github.com/Heather/Nemerle/blob/VS2013/snippets/VS2010/Nemerle.VisualStudio/Nemerle.VisualStudio-VS-2013.csproj

What should be added to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [your .vsixmanifest](https://github.com/Heather/Nemerle/blob/VS2013/snippets/VS2010/Nemerle.VisualStudio/source.extension.vsixmanifest), which is what specifies the "reference". I would expect that reference to still work (MPF versions aren't supposed to go away), so I'm surprised something might have gotten busted here. In any case, .vsix references are simply there to state what is needed...they don't actually do anything. You can probably delete the reference with no ill effects.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Solved it by first installing [**Guidance Automation Extensions (GAX)**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25e4b5e9-65e4-4950-967d-5f1e6a9dcbeb) and later try installing the desired `vsix` file.